# how to empty a file when a process is continuosuly writing to it

Tags: c, linux

My scenario is following:

A program named a.out is continuously writing "hello world" in an infinite loop and redirecting its output to file name test.log.

I want to empty (truncate) test.log while a.out is continuously writing to test.log.

Comment: `echo "" > test.log`?

Comment: I have tried this but test.log size is increasing continuously

Comment: Do you close file descriptor after write "Hello world"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop the program you describe refilling the file without stopping the program. You could `kill -STOP $(pgrep yourprogram)` (and `kill -CONT` it later) or just outright blow it away.

To truncate the file,

> `$ truncate -ssize file`

where `size` is anything reasonably close to its current size. HFS+ apparently won't do sparse allocation, but everything else modern will.

(edit 2:  a little testing with `dd` says specifying `-s0` might well work, if you're inclined to try).

To see the space actually used to store a file, `du -h`*`file`*. `ls` will report its apparent size.

(edit: [the Arch wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sparse_file) straightened me out on the subject of creating sparse files)

Answer (score 0):

The idiom I've seen is

```
> filename
```

There are some other options [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88808/empty-the-contents-of-a-file).

Comment: I have tried all but file size is increasing continuously

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   char buffer [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "w");
   if (pFile == NULL)
       perror ("Error opening file");
   else
     fclose (pFile);

    while(1) {
        pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "a");
        fputs("Hello World\n", pFile);
        fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

To clear file you can use

```
$echo a > myfile.txt
```

Comment: Not the same as the OP is asking: you are `fopen`-ing & `fclose`-ing in a loop. The OP's other program is probably `fopen`-ing once.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easily possible if the program has kept open the `test.log` file. Whatever other processes are doing, that process is having an open file descriptor to it.

You might try doing some [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) in the other program.

You should consider using [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) facilities instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. Use this command to empty test.log:

```
gdb -batch-silent -p `pidof a.out` -ex "call ftruncate(1,0)" -ex "call lseek(1,0,0)"
```

Some explanation:

- `pidof a.out` returns PID of your `a.out` process.
- you said that you redirected output to a file. That is why I use 1 as
  the number of a file desciptor in the `ftruncate` and `lseek` calls
- ftruncate - truncate a file to a specified length
- lseek - reposition read/write file offset

This is example for a command `seq 1 1000000000 > seq.txt`:

```
$ ls -l seq.txt && gdb -batch-silent -p `pidof seq` -ex "call (void)ftruncate(1,0)" -ex "call lseek(1,0,0)" && ls -l seq.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user unix_users 706019328 Jun 10 09:58 seq.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user unix_users 65536 Jun 10 09:58 seq.txt
```